# jQuery convert object values into numbers

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to convert object values into integers:

```
var array = { 
  borderTopLeftRadius:"0px", 
  borderTopRightRadius:"0px", 
  borderBottomLeftRadius:"0px",
  borderBottomRightRadius:"0px"
}
```

I want to keep the same structure, but the result should look like this:

```
var array = { 
  borderTopLeftRadius:0, 
  borderTopRightRadius:0, 
  borderBottomLeftRadius:0,
  borderBottomRightRadius:0
}
```

I've been using `$map` to do it, but I cant make it work

```
var newArray = $.map(array, function(value){
    return parseInt(value, 10);
});
```

Comment: Sidenote: Your `array` isn't actually an array.  It's an object.

Comment: Yes, it say in the title and description as well.

Comment: @Alko But you're trying to map an object...?

Comment: @AndrewLi: `parseInt("0px", 10)` works as expected.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, forgot that if the number is the first thing in the string, non-numericals are stripped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you've an **[Object literal `{}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)** and not an **[array `[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)**, you could use jQuery method **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** to achieve that :

```js
var myObject = { 
  borderTopLeftRadius:"0px", 
  borderTopRightRadius:"0px", 
  borderBottomLeftRadius:"0px",
  borderBottomRightRadius:"0px"
};
var newObject = {};

$.each( myObject, function( key, value ) {
  newObject[key]=parseInt(value, 10);
});

console.log(newObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfect. I have accepted your answer. I never said the I want to convert an array. Title says an Object. Just because I named variable array, it dos not mean that. It was for demo purpose.

Comment: Just to be clear alko people are confused because you used the arrays tag which suggests the post is about arrays. And a variable name is supposed to be suggestive as to what the variable holds.

Answer (score 2):

Your `array` is *not* an array.  JavaScript does not have associative arrays, it has objects - which is what you have.

jQuery's [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function works on both arrays and objects, but it only returns arrays.  Thus, your object is *converted* into an array.

You could loop over the keys of the object and build a new object with the integer values:

```
var newArray = {};
Object.keys(array).forEach(function(key){
    newArray[key] = parseInt(array[key], 10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result with a `for` loop

```js
var array = { 
  borderTopLeftRadius:"0px", 
  borderTopRightRadius:"0px", 
  borderBottomLeftRadius:"0px",
  borderBottomRightRadius:"0px"
}

for (var key in array) {
  array[key] = parseInt(array[key],10);
}

console.log(array);
```